# Problems using template meta-programming to count number of set bits in integer

Tags: c++

As an experiment, I'm trying to write template code to count the number of set bits in an integer at compile-time. Here is my first attempt:

```
template<unsigned long long x>
struct BitCount
{
    static const int result = (x == 0) ? 0 : ((x & 1) + BitCount<(x >> 1)>::result);
};
```

This gives errors.

Visual Studio 2013

`error C2065: 'result' : undeclared identifier`

ideone.com

`error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum) instantiating ‘BitCount<0ull>::result’`

How can I fix this error properly?

Ok so I changed it to

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<unsigned long long x>
struct BitCount
{
    static const int result;
};

template<unsigned long long x>
const int BitCount<x>::result = (x == 0) ? 0 : ((x & 1) + BitCount<(x >> 1)>::result);

template<unsigned long long x>
int bitcount()
{
    return BitCount<x>::result;
}

int main()
{
    cout << bitcount<5>() << endl;
    cout << bitcount<1>() << endl;
    cout << bitcount<3>() << endl;
    cout << bitcount<0>() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

ideone.com correctly outputs: 2 1 2 0

Visual Studio 2013 incorrectly outputs: 1 1 2 0

Is this a bug in VS or is something in my code incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: A `unsigned long long` has the same number of bits regardless of its value.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, bits set to 1

Comment: This would actually be a lot better as a `constexpr` function.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did.

Comment: @Neil "Problems using template meta-programming to count number of bits in integer" Right there in the title

Answer (score 5):

You need a specialization for the terminating case of zero:

```
template<>
struct BitCount<0>
{
    static const int result = 0;
};
```

Otherwise, you simply rely on the primary template so that `BitCount<0>::result` is defined as `true ? 0 : BitCount<0>::result` which is an endlessly recursive template instantiation. It still needs to instantiate the else-clause even if it isn't evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specialize for the base-case, or you get infinite compile-time recursion there (the definition of the base-case is dependent on the definition of the base-case).
Also, it looks better if you inline the initialization:

```
template<unsigned long long x>
struct PopCount
{
    static const int result = (x&1)+BitCount<(x>>1)>::result;
};
template<>
struct PopCount<0ULL>
{
    static const int result = 0;
}
```

BTW: Using `constexpr` for the result member instead of `const static` is better, even better a function instead (C++11):

```
constexpr int popCount(unsigned long long x) {
    return x ? int(x&1) + popCount(x>>1) : 0;
}
```

As a last step, make the function iterative for better performance when executing it at runtime (C++14).

```
constexpr int popCount(unsigned long long x) {
    int r = 0;
    for(; x; x &= x-1)
        ++r;
    return r;
}
```

This assignment `x &= x-1;` clears the lowest-order set bit, so fewer iterations neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following:

```
template<unsigned long long x>
struct BitCount
{
    static constexpr const int result = (x & 1) + BitCount<(x >> 1)>::result;
};

template<>
struct BitCount<0>
{
    static constexpr const int result = 0;
};
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/fy3NB6)

or simply a constexpr function

```
constexpr int bitCount(unsigned long long x)
{
    return (x == 0) ? 0 : int(x & 1ULL) + bitCount(x >> 1);
}
```

BTW, you may use the bit trick `x & (x-1)` to mask off the lowest set bit instead of doing `x >> 1` as follow:

```
constexpr int bitCount(unsigned long long x)
{
    return (x == 0) ? 0 : 1 + bitCount(x & (x - 1));
}
```

Comment: _"BTW"_ Really? 4(00000100) & 3(00000011) is 0(00000000).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I may be unclear, I mean that the function can be rewritten as follow : `return (x == 0) ? 0 : 1 + bitCount(x & (x - 1));` instead of iterate from 4 to 2 to 1 to 0 with `x >> 1`.

Comment: Right ok the phrase _"to remove the lowest set bit"_ threw me off as it doesn't discuss what else is different in this alternative implementation. It's clearer now you have code, though a set of examples and explanations would make it easier to understand, and this a more complete answer.